# How can I batch compress and decompress Monkey's Audio In Ubuntu?

Tags: sound

I am using the command `mac` in terminal to compress and decompress Monkey's Audio files. However, I want to find a way to do it to more than one file at a time. Is there a trick for the `mac` program that I don't know, or is there another program that can help?

I'm stuck using the Window's GUI under WINE. Help free me from this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `mac` does one file at a time, so you have to work around it.

Assuming the files you want to encode/decode are in specific folders, or sub-folders, and not arbitrary paths, you can do it with a combination of *find*, *sed* and *xargs*.

For example, to encode all WAV files in a specific folder and all its subfolders, with the output files simply having the APE extension, using the fast `-c1000` preset, you would type:

```
find ~/path/to/folder -name *.wav | sed 's/....$//g' \
   | xargs -I MACFILE mac "MACFILE.wav" "MACFILE.ape" -c1000
```

#### Explanation:

- `find` finds all files with the wav extension in and under the given path, and outputs them.

  - You can use `` `pwd` `` (with the backticks) as shorthand for the current folder.
  - Add the argument `-maxdepth 0` to stick to the current folder only and not go into subfolders.
- The *sed* expression deletes (i.e. replaces with "blank") the last four characters of each filename returned by find, which is the extension `.wav` or `.ape`
- *xargs* feeds each filename piped in to the `mac` command.

  - The `-I MACFILE` tells *xargs* to replace each occurrence of *MACFILE* with the input (filename); this way we get files with proper extensions and not `.wav.ape`, etc.

---

To decode *within the current folder only*, and output to a custom folder, for example:

```
find `pwd` -name *.ape -maxdepth 0 | sed 's/....$//g' \
   | xargs -I MACFILE mac "MACFILE.ape" "/home/ryan/decodes/MACFILE.wav" -d
```

---

> Note: *find* is one of those utilities that are almost limitless (see `man find`). With the right `-exec` and `-printf` options (and maybe more), *find* may alone be sufficient without needing the *sed* and *xargs*, and I'm sure someone will point that out :) . But I find this easier to explain and understand.

Comment: it works!!! Sorry for the delayed response, I keep forgetting to accept the answer! Works with no problems, excellent answer! :)

Comment: To be honest, the reason I was asking was because I needed to batch decompress .ape to .wav, then to .flac. I had a public domain set of music that I had downloaded, but it was .ape. So, i honestly wanted to put it to .flac. However, I wanted to know a batch way. And I figured, while I was at it, why not have a question that dealt with batch compression and decompression? ;) Help the rest of the community as I figure out my answer.